# `Boolean()` and `!!`, is this intended?

Tags: typescript

`Boolean` type type infers to be a `boolean` type, and `!!` operator type infers to be a `true` or `false`.
Is it intended? and why?
Here's the code:

```js
const truthy = true
const falsy = false

const truthyWithBoolean = Boolean(truthy) // boolean
const truthyWithNot = !!truthy            // true
const falsyWithBoolean = Boolean(falsy)   // boolean
const falsyWithNot = !!falsy              // false
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBXKALAnjAvHJBTAUKJLAGYCGANhBtuVQYeNDsugOoCWqAQiCBbjJgsMXv0FgAFAlZoAlDAD0imACM+AoY2ItUaTqgByIWNgCEZmXpg3bdm8pYEizOtQMoxm4di8TJbvK2juriWi6klO5cKMamMBaB9snBKm64QA)

Comment: How did you get `Boolean` from `const truthyWithBoolean = Boolean(truthy)` ? and not `true`?

Comment: If you run `console.log(typeof truthyWithBoolean, truthyWithBoolean); console.log(typeof truthyWithNot, truthyWithNot);` you'll get `"boolean",  true` for both so I don't really understand your question.

Comment: It’s a habit imported from C, where it has some use in coercing Boolean values to 0 or -1. Completely pointless here, or in any language with a first-class Boolean type.

Comment: @Owenn oops that's `boolean`. It was my mistake, sorry. I edited the post.

Comment: Commenters don't seem to realize this is a *type system* question and not a *runtime* question, so maybe you should [edit] the question to show you're talking about TypeScript's inferred types. The answer is that the `!` operator is supported directly as part of the language and it knows that `!true` is `false` and `!false` is `true`, whereas `Boolean` is just a "coerce thing to boolean" call signature that returns `boolean` because it wasn't intended to detect truthiness. It's working as intended, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @jcalz woah, so `Boolean` means "it will be something which is boolean type", and `!!` means "it will be true or false". is it right?

Comment: • No, `true | false` and `boolean` are the same; it's more like `!!` tracks what you're doing to the input while `Boolean` doesn't even try. • The canonical answer to this question is: see [ms/TS#16655](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16655). If you want to *try* to make `Boolean` act like `!!` you could merge in something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2glrN) shows, but it's probably fragile and not worth it. Just use `!!` if you need that behavior. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz It was soooo fruitful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

They behave differently because the primary use cases for `!` and `Boolean()` are different. TypeScript lacks human intelligence and cannot simply look at two different pieces of code like `!!x` and `Boolean(x)` and say "these do the same thing" unless someone explicitly programs that into the compiler. That has not been done because such support has not been a high enough priority to be worth the effort.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#16655](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16655) for a canonical answer. `Boolean` can't be used to check truthiness in TypeScript because it wasn't originally written to; they decided to implement something like this in [microsoft/TypeScript#29955](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29955) and then rolled it back in [microsoft/TypeScript#31515](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31515) because it interacted poorly with other more important features.

---

The primary use of the [logical NOT operator `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) is to negate a condition. Consider the following function:

```
function foo(x: number[] | string) {
    if (!Array.isArray(x)) {
        console.log(x.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

This function compiles with no error because TypeScript can use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to see that `Array.isArray(x)` will be `true` if and only if `x` is an array, and so `!Array.isArray(x)` will be `true` if and only if `x` is *not* an array, which for a value of type `number[] | string` means that it must be a `string`.

In order for this to work, TypeScript needs to track what `!` does fairly closely. Among other things, it needs to know that `!true` is `false` and `!false` is `true`.  That means it cares about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of what it operates on.

And since `!!` is not its own operator, but the repeated application of the `!` operator, it also ends up keeping track of the literal `true` and `false` types and what happens with them.

Additionally, JavaScript doesn't allow you to define or overload operators. So TypeScript doesn't give you a way for users to tweak how operators behave; its analysis of `!` is "baked into" the language.

---

On the other hand the `Boolean` value isn't an operator, so its behavior isn't baked into the language. It is [declared in the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/075ebb492827ea2fa1a6229ed764d280ee5ac6f0/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L533-L539) as

```
declare var Boolean: BooleanConstructor;
```

where the relevant part of `BooleanConstructor` looks like

```
interface BooleanConstructor {
    <T>(value?: T): boolean; 
}
```

When you write `Boolean(x)` you're using that [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures), which takes a `value` of any type whatsoever (not sure why it's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), probably fallout of the feature rollback linked at the top) and produces a `boolean`.  It doesn't try to determine if `T` is truthy or not and then narrow the output to `true` or `false`. It always produces `boolean`, no matter what. That's what you see. It behaves as designed.

As mentioned above this was changed at some point to be a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), but it had weird side effects.

If you need something like this in your own code base, you could [merge in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) your own call signature that behaves however you'd like.  For your example, maybe something like this:

```
interface BooleanConstructor {
    <const T>(
        x: T
    ): T extends false | 0 | 0n | "" | null | undefined ? false : true;
}

Boolean(true); // true
Boolean(false); // false
Boolean("abc") // true
Boolean(100) // true
Boolean(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "") // boolean
Boolean(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b") // true
```

But such things add complexity and have weird edge cases, so you should take care that the cure isn't worse than the disease (see [the comment that sealed the fate of ms/TS#29955](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31515#issuecomment-494621036)).  For example, the above [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) will do wrong things in some common cases:

```
Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)) // true!! uh oh
```

It thinks `Boolean(someRandomNumber)` is `true`, whereas it must be `boolean` to allow for `0`.  You could try to patch it, but these patches start looking very complex:

```
interface BooleanConstructor {
    <const T>(
        x: T
    ): T extends false | 0 | 0n | "" | null | undefined ? false :
        string extends T ? boolean :
        number extends T ? boolean :
        true
}

Boolean(true); // true
Boolean(false); // false
Boolean("abc") // true
Boolean(100) // true
Boolean(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "") // boolean
Boolean(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b") // true    
Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)) // boolean, okay
```

And then it's not clear if you've covered the edge cases, or if your new call signature has other effects you weren't expecting. It's likely to be fragile and thus unlikely to be worth it.  Especially since you can just use `!!` instead.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhAhAKAHgLmRMAWwCMBTAJwG0BdZAH2QGcZy4IBzASmQG9hkByOCGQYAhAEFy5AIYBPAHRxGU2XOydufQTuRQkjBABtSCownbYFMBAFUADvYoBhGY1IZNAbn6CAvsABwMBsMBQgMlCkyABC6CYyEM4GLGCwCOS8vgIAPPoQzMgAKgB8GNm6uMUVnHhFyKRYYRAAJoyoMkbu9MgADD29KAwARMM9BEZGPZAtpCBspC3IAPwdXdF4qaQ+AXHGpIkYW5xeyAD0Z8hbwHsJEBgR6yfnl4-uN-EH98MyxFDD3AuV3IYFIH32hwAjL1eoDLtdbl8MABZGQwAAWClkrQQhE8yByfQUAFYVsgfmM8KM4chiJ9EuC7ii0ZjsS1cfjCb0SWSKcgqcQAS9gaCdIykaiMQoQOYMsypWyOdwAFTIABMmmFWzEYmQYHRyAQ6OCEBkhFIjHskWiAAlCIQsjpQuFrbF6UkUiD0pltLpcvlCqVyn6-VUihUdLVig0mqRWu03tEGP1k0NyWMGBMpgwZnMFktVon+RGQ8xWBwY802tHVnSISgcCW-QQSBRK3Hq-Va+7iyHdNcdAEdLMoEYZORogGYG763hEYlkgVUt6fBV5-djqcgQPBOuHp13M8gYm1+6MD8-kLtyCwTo99DYVqb6f6-LWYl2XjuFyeas+VSr0uOs7hfJlJXfHEvwJIlST-GRKXJQUaS2MU7zPcDpVlcg3yxD8lWQVUNRpYCvgAGkNABreRgj8IA)